# Pass lists of JSON objects as JSON object in knockout

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have a series of knockout bound checkboxes on the client side that I need to pass via AJAX to the server which needs the request to be in JSON format. The checkboxes on the front end look like so:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: Items">
     <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.returnedItems, attr: { value: itemNumber}" />
 </div>
```

By making the checkedValue be $data it is storing the Item object in the array.

The js that handles the AJAX call is *roughly* this (altered some because inner company helper functions make it different):

```
self.returnedItems = ko.observableArray()
self.showArray = function () {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: ko.toJSON(self.returnedItems()),
        dataType: 'json',
    });
}
```

the `ko.toJSON(self.returnedItems())` is used to turn the list of objects into JSON string to be passed. However, the result it gives me is this:

> [{"item":"12088","desc":"Radio","qty":1},{"item":"1T1S","desc":TV",qty":1}]

This in itself is not proper JSON format (which makes sense in hindsighht) as it doesn't have a key associated with the array outer brackets, it would need to look something like this:

> {itemList: [{"item":"12088","desc":"Radio","qty":1},{"item":"1T1S","desc":TV",qty":1}]}

But I can't for the life of me find a good way too accomplish this without altering the AJAX call to send this:

`data: "{itemList:" + ko.toJSON(self.returnedItems()) + "}"`

Which works but seems hacky. Is there a simpler way to pass a well formatted JSON list of objects in Knockout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is valid JSON, it's just not a JSON *object*. If your ajax needs a JSON object, you should be able to wrap it like so: `ko.toJSON({itemList: self.returnedItems()})`

Comment: That's perfect! I know it doesn't look like _much_ of a difference but clearing up those plus signs is a big help. Thanks